# Power BI Service & advanced transformations after refresh

Tags: powerbi, powerquery

I've done some advanced data transformations in Power Query connected to an SQL source. I've built a few columns to retreive information from the item dimensions.

```
#"Canopy column" = Table.AddColumn(dbo_INV1, "Canopy", each if ([Dscription] = null or [Dscription] = "") then "" else if  Text.PositionOf([Dscription], "#")=-1  then "" else Text.End([Dscription], Text.Length([Dscription]) - Text.PositionOf([Dscription], "#"))),
    // -1 means nothing found related to the search otherwise all the text on the right after the #. 
    // First check if the itemcode is null or blank, if so return nothing, if not search for the - in the item text. 
    // If the - is found, search for the shapes in an upper formula and return the shape. 
    #"Shape column" = Table.AddColumn(#"Canopy column", "Shape", each let 
result_search = if [ItemCode] = null or [ItemCode] = "" then "" else if Text.PositionOf([ItemCode],"-")=-1 then "" else Text.Upper(Text.Start([ItemCode],Text.PositionOf([ItemCode], "-"))),
        Substrings = {"SQ", "OCT", "HEX", "RECT", "ROUND"},
        Result = List.First(List.Select(Substrings, (substring) => Text.Contains(result_search, substring))),
        Final = if Result <> null then Result else ""
in Final),
```

(there is more code but the canopy column works and the shape doesn't work).

This works in Power Query and my Power BI report. Also when I publish it to the Power BI service environment it still works. However, when I refresh my data my calculations don't seem to work anymore. I've tried to see the data and the columns that I use are still available and have the correct data to perform the queries on.

Does anyone have an idea?

Comment: I assume that the data you are refreshing to use is somehow different from the sample data that you build the query from.   What errors are you getting? How does the refreshed source data differ from sample data?

Comment: Also, why not try    Canopy = Text.AfterDelimiter([Dscription],"#")    and    result_search = Text.BeforeDelimiter([ItemCode],"-")

Comment: @horseyride, thanks the data that I'm refreshing is two days older than the local SQL backup, so it must have some similarities. I also exported the refreshed data and loaded this again in Power Query, this seemed to work. 

Thanks for the suggestion regarding the delimiter, it's more efficient, but it doesn't solve the problem.